# Write a number with two decimal places SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, decimal, number-formatting

How do you write a number with two decimal places for sql server?

Answer (score 255):

Try this

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),YOURCOLUMN)
```

such as

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),2.999999)
```

will result in output `3.00`

[image]

Comment: I tried SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),10.11111)
it returned 10.11
same result for 
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),'10.11111')
it was in Sql Server 2008 R2

Comment: I get the error message "ERROR: syntax error at or near ",""...referring to the comma right before the column I want to reference.

Comment: `SELECT CAST(2.999 as DECIMAL(10,2))` will also return`3.00` as an alternative

Answer (score 77):

Use `Str()` Function. It takes three arguments(the number, the number total characters to display, and the number of decimal places to display

```
  Select Str(12345.6789, 12, 3)
```

displays:  '   12345.679'  ( 3 spaces, 5 digits 12345, a decimal point, and three decimal digits (679). - it rounds if it has to truncate, (unless the integer part is too large for the total size, in which case asterisks are displayed instead.)

for a Total of 12 characters, with 3 to the right of decimal point.

Comment: `it rounds if it has to truncate`... unless the integer part is too large for the total size, in which case asterisks are displayed instead. This is mentioned in the [documentation for `STR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx). Here's a quote from that page: `STR(1223,2) truncates the result set to **.`

Answer (score 40):

Generally you can define the precision of a number in SQL by defining it with parameters. For most cases this will be `NUMERIC(10,2)` or `Decimal(10,2)` - will define a column as a Number with 10 total digits with a precision of 2 (decimal places).

*Edited for clarity*

Comment: It can also be declared as DECIMAL(10, 2).

Comment: This is wrong for several reasons.  It's not number, it's numeric or decimal.  You say numeric(10,2) allows 10 places before the decimal point, which is also wrong.  numeric(10,2) allows for 10 total digits with 2 places after the decimal point.  Range = -99999999.99 to 99999999.99

Comment: @G Mastros: It appears you are right on the precision point. On the actual naming of the the convention, in many of SQL implementations NUMBER is a valid type. Although I will admit to not knowing the case of sqlserver

Comment: @GMastros came to say the same thing. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258832%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 34):

This is how the kids are doing it today:

```
DECLARE @test DECIMAL(18,6) = 123.456789
SELECT FORMAT(@test, '##.##')
```

123.46

Comment: FORMAT function is available from version 2012 onwards.

Comment: or: SELECT FORMAT(@test, '.##')

Comment: If the input data was:

`DECLARE @test DECIMAL(18,6) = 0.456789`

then `SELECT FORMAT(@test, '##.##')` returns:

`.46`

How do you get it to show the leading zero:

`0.46` ?

Comment: To get a leading 0, try SELECT FORMAT(@test, '#0.##')

Comment: I think you would most likely want to use '0.00' instead of '#.##'. The # will ignore trailing zeroes so 5.10 will become 5.1 or 4.00 will just show 4 on its own. The '0.00' format will ensure you always get exactly two decimal places.

Comment: Even though the question is not specific, `FORMAT` does not return a number itr returns a varchar so it only adds to data type confusion here

Answer (score 20):

This work for me and always keeps two digits fractions

23.1 ==> 23.10

25.569 ==> 25.56

1 ==> 1.00

```
Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),Value1) as nvarchar) AS Value2
```

[Code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyBiN.jpg)

Comment: try the STR() function from Charles Bretana above. It works like your formula but will do rounding on your 25.569 example.

Comment: what happens here if the original value is zero?

Answer (score 18):

If you only need two decimal places, simplest way is..

```
SELECT CAST(12 AS DECIMAL(16,2))
```

OR

```
SELECT CAST('12' AS DECIMAL(16,2))
```

*Output*

```
12.00
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're fine with **rounding** the number instead of truncating it, then it's just:

```
ROUND(column_name,decimals)
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to have two decimals is SQL Format with "F" parameter:

```
SELECT FORMAT(5634.6334, 'F')
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I use

```
FORMAT(10, 'N2')
```

outputs 10.00

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 declare @MyFloatVal float;

    set @MyFloatVal=(select convert(decimal(10, 2), 10.254000))

    select  @MyFloatVal

    Convert(decimal(18,2),r.AdditionAmount) as AdditionAmount
```

Comment: Do not use floats unless you have a specific reason. Floats are imprecise

Answer (score 0):

This will allow total 10 digits with 2 values after the decimal. It means that it can accomodate the value value before decimal upto 8 digits and 2 after decimal.

To validate, put the value in the following query.

```
DECLARE vtest  number(10,2);
BEGIN
SELECT 10.008 INTO vtest FROM dual;
dbms_output.put_line(vtest);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to try below, e.g  60/100 = 0.6, SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(60*0.01)) = 0.60

```
  SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(YourValue*0.01))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FORMAT(104565556.785, '0.00')

Output: 104565556.79

SELECT FORMAT(104565556, '0.00')

Output: 104565556.00
```