# MySQL is cutting '00' in decimals

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a decimal column with a lenght = 9 and decimals = 2.

If I put a value of `21.59` (for example) it works **ok**.

If I put `52.00` it writes only `52`. I need to keep `52.00` instead.

> Master question: Can the database store the value this way? Instead of
>   using format/cast in select to retrieve the value...

As noted bellow, this make sense:

> "You shouldn't worry about display formatting issues at the database
>   level but at the ... display level"

Comment: Use a string column type, as opposed to decimal?

Comment: I am not trying to use workarounds. Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't worry about display formatting issues at the database level but at the ... display level... Data stored in its display format (basically must be a string) is incredibly hard to work with  and inflexible.

Comment: You can find what you need [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6402265/1492106).

Comment: int with `.00` makes little sense, unless you have it as a `string`. take a look at http://php.net/manual/pl/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_format) function:

```
select format(mycolumn, 2) from mytable;
```

This also has the effect of adding thousand's separator into the number, so you would get output like `123,456.70`. There are workarounds if this doesn't work for you.

Given that MySQL doesn't have the world's best facilities for formatting numbers, display issues like this are usually handled in client code.

Comment: OP wants to **store** the information with the decimals, not merely display it

Comment: The information is already being stored. The problem is that it is not being *displayed*.

Comment: @hd1 `.00` is superfluous information. There should be no reason to save it in the database.

Comment: I agree with @Juhana. Databases do try to help you. Imagine you have one million numbers with `.00`. Thats 3 million additional and empty bytes clogging up your harddrive and slowing down your database. That's a LOT of stuff to remember. in any case, reformat the number in your `view`

Comment: Actually, those `.00` are already there. They occupy less than 1 byte in total though. Since version 5.0.3 MySQL stores numbers using a binary representation and not as strings. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html