# how to type cast database fields in select query in cakephp 3.X?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

in my table, I have a decimal field of quantity. The value of 'quantity' in the database is 1.00 but when I selecting it from query, it is giving me integer 1. However, if the value will 1.25, it gives the same float value 1.25.
Here is my query and output -

**Query**

```
$app_cart = $this->AppCart->find()->select(['AppCart.id','item'=>'Items.name','price'=>'Items.sales_rate','quantity'=>'AppCart.quantity'])
        ->where(['AppCart.user_id'=>1])->contain(['Items']);
```

**Output**

```
{
"success": true,
"message": "List Found",
"app_cart": [
    {
        "id": 4,
        "item": "KANGAN SAREE",
        "price": 1375,
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "item": "KANGAN SAREE",
        "price": 1375,
        "quantity": 1
    }
]}
```

**I have tried**

```
$app_cart
        ->selectTypeMap()
        ->addDefaults([
            'quantity' => 'decimal'
        ]);
```

Comment: It's not reading it as an integer, it's just displaying that way. Pretty normal behaviour for PHP; `print 1.00` and `print (float)1.00` will display simply `1`. If you have 1.20 in your database, it'll show as 1.2. This is obviously machine-readable output you're generating here, is there a problem with the recipient handling it incorrectly? Or you're just debugging and thinking that something might be wrong because it's not showing all the decimals?

Comment: you can fix it on DB level `select format(mycolumn, 2) from mytable;` [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578410/mysql-is-cutting-00-in-decimals)

Comment: @tphobe9312 how to implement DB level in cakephp query?

Comment: @GregSchmidt so there is no way to get 1.00 in output?

Comment: I meant to say just use `format` function in select method

Comment: I would use the `Number` helper in the view.

Comment: There are various ways to get 1.00 in the output. I was asking whether you truly need to get 1.00 in this output; what you've shown seems like the sort of thing where you wouldn't necessarily need it, and doing extra work for no reason is never a good idea. Maybe this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: @GregSchmidt actually I am making API for Android. The Android team needs if the value will decimal at any point of time so all value should come in decimal.

Comment: @LinkinTED I can't use number format because i have to send it in API

Comment: The android app will have to validate/parse/cast the value anyways, so why bother with this if the rule is "_field x must be a decimal_"? Trailing zero's should be totally irrelevant in that situation.