# How to round a float value into 2 decimal place?

Tags: asp.net, sql, decimal

I need to convert a float number into 2 decimal format.I have tried **`Math.round(AmountSpent1,2)`**
This is my code:

```
float AmountSpent1 = float.Parse(FixedAmount);
Math.Round(AmountSpent1, 2);
```

Comment: See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441600/write-a-number-with-two-decimal-places-sql-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float AmountSpent1 = float.Parse(FixedAmount);
decimal m =Convert.ToDecimal(AmountSpent1);
decimal d = Math.Round(m, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply try this one

**`DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("#.##");`**

*For Example*

`float AmountSpent1 = float.Parse(FixedAmount);

 System.out.println(df.format(AmountSpent1));`