# Rounding Decimal in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am trying to round the result of my code to 2 decimal places, but ROUND isn't working. Any help? Thanks!

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT [Id], [attempts], [total], (round(attempts / total,(2))) AS [Percentage] FROM [Game]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Here is a [useful link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441600/write-a-number-with-two-decimal-places-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet you could use

```
CAST(ROUND(attempts/total,2) as DECIMAL(12,2))
```

OR

```
attempts/CAST(total as DECIMAL(12,2))
```

OR

```
CAST(attempts AS DECIMAL(12,2))/total
```

Comment: Thank you Jeroen! Actually, the first choice was the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this
      " 
             SelectCommand="SELECT [Id], [attempts], [total], round((attempts / total),2) AS [Percentage] FROM [Game]">

**UPDATE:**

Have you tried:

```
SELECT Cast( 2.555 as decimal(53,2))
```

This would return 2.55 . Is that what you want?