# I need to remove leading zeros after a decimal point

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

this is my first time posting here and I am a basic SQL user and need help.

I have a `varchar` column that stores data like below:

```
Year.Docid
2007.000000001
2007.000000002
2007.000000003
2007.000000004
2007.000000005
2007.000000006
```

I need to join this data to another table that does not have all the zeros after the decimal, can someone please show me how to get the data to look like below:

```
Year Docid
2007.1
2007.2
2007.3
2007.4
2007.5
2007.6
```

I am using MICROSOFT SQL SERVER 2012

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Example 1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380197/sql-rounding-off-to-2-decimal-places

Example 2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441600/write-a-number-with-two-decimal-places-sql-server

Comment: @LC: the OP does not want to round the number

Comment: @LJ-C. I don't think this is about rounding

Comment: Is this column a VARCHAR?

Comment: Yes the column is VARCHAR

Comment: forgot to mention that this is in MS SQL

Comment: Please edit your question to add information, don't put it in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the format is fixed, i.e. `YYYY.NNNNNNNNN`, you could just get the last 9 characters, convert them to `int`, convert the result back to `varchar` and concatenate back to the first 5 characters:

```
LEFT([Year.Docid], 5) + CAST(CAST(RIGHT([Year.Docid], 9) AS int) AS varchar(10))
```

However, it would make more sense to store Year and Docid as two separate `int` columns, in both tables. It is much easier to assemble them just for the output than do this processing every time *and* join on the results of it.

Comment: WORKED LIKE A GEM!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To turn the long format into the short format:

```
SELECT LEFT('2007.000000001',5) + CAST(CAST(RIGHT('2007.000000001',LEN('2007.000000001')-5) AS int)AS VARCHAR)
```

...

To use that in a join:

```
SELECT
...
FROM
   TABLE_1 T1
   INNER JOIN TABLE_2 T2
   ON LEFT(T1.pk,5) + CAST(CAST(RIGHT(T1.pk,LEN(T1.pk)-5) AS int)AS VARCHAR) = T2.pk
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, assuming both columns are varchar, something like this should do you:

```
select *
from table_1 t1
join table_2 t2 on t2.docid = left(t2.docid,4)
                            + '.'
                            + convert(varchar,convert(int,right( t2.docid, len(t2.docid)-5 )))
```

You should bear in mind that making the one table's column an expression means that for that table/column, the query optimizer cannot use any indexes in the query plan.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of work, but accomplishes the task of removing the zeros from the right of the dot:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(YearDocid, 0, CHARINDEX('.', yearDocId)) + 
       REPLACE(SUBSTRING(yearDocId, 
                         CHARINDEX('.', yearDocId), 
                         LEN(yearDocID)), 
               '0', '')
FROM tab1;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5068/23)</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

SELECT CONCAT(PARSENAME([Col_Varchar],2),'.',CONVERT(INT,PARSENAME([Col_Varchar],1))) FROM Tbl_sample