# mysql decimal placement for query

Tags: mysql

I am working a MySQL statement, but when I query the database with the statement it gives me a long return of decimals.  How do I only return the decimal placement of 2 spots?

For example, I am getting a return of `8.990999794006347` and I want to get a return placement of just `8.99`. Here is my statement to query the database or just that table:

```
Select movieID, title, year, discountPrice - (.10 * discountPrice) AS 'My Price' From Movie;
```

I just need the decimal placement to be of 2.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-functions.html

Comment: Check this post
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441600/write-a-number-with-two-decimal-places-sql-server][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441600/write-a-number-with-two-decimal-places-sql-server

Comment: Use MySQL's [`ROUND()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) function.

Comment: @RocketHazmat i seen a couple of example but where would i place the round method?

Comment: Also how do i apply this to my statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`ROUND()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) method around your "value".

```
Select movieID, title, year,
    ROUND(discountPrice - (.10 * discountPrice), 2) AS 'My Price'
From Movie;
```