# SQLCMD - removing timestamp from date & formatting fields to 2 decimal places

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd, sapb1

I am using SQLCMD to export out a SQL query from my server.

One of the fields I am exporting is a date field - but when it is exported it has a time stamp as well - eg:
2015-12-15 00:00:00.000

How do I go about removing the timestamp from the date such that it is:
2015-12-15

Further to this - in other exported fields that have numerical data, it is automatically exporting to 6 decimal places. How do I go about formatting the fields to 2 decimal places?

At the moment the SQLCMD is looking like this:

```
SQLCMD -S <server name> -d <db name> -U <username> -P <password> -Q 
"set nocount on;
SELECT 
T0.DocNum, 
T0.CardCode, 
T0.CardName, 
T0.DocDate, 
T0.DocTime, 
T0.U_FreightEntry, 
T1.ItemCode, 
T1.Dscription, 
T1.CodeBars, 
T1.Quantity, 
(((100-T0.DiscPrcnt)/100)*T1.Price) as 'Price per unit ex GST', 
((((100-T0.DiscPrcnt)/100)*T1.Price)*1.1) as 'Price per Unit Inc GST', 
(SELECT T6.Price FROM ITM1 T6 where T6.ItemCode = T5.Itemcode and T6.PriceList = '2') as 'RRP inc GST per unit', T0.VatSum, T0.DocTotal as 'Inv Total' 
FROM dbo.OINV  T0 INNER JOIN dbo.INV1  T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry 
INNER JOIN dbo.OCRD  T2 ON T0.CardCode = T2.CardCode 
INNER JOIN dbo.OCRG  T3 ON T2.GroupCode = T3.GroupCode 
INNER JOIN OPLN T4 ON T2.ListNum = T4.ListNum 
INNER JOIN OITM T5 ON T1.ItemCode = T5.ItemCode 
INNER JOIN ITM1 T6 ON T5.ItemCode = T6.ItemCode and T6.Pricelist = '1'
WHERE T3.GroupName = 'NEWSXPRESS' and T0.DocDate = '20151215'
ORDER BY T0.DocNum" 
-s "," -o "<server address>\NewsxpressInvoices_%DATE:~4,2%_%DATE:~7,2%_%DATE:~-4%.csv" -h-1 -s"~" -W -w 999
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Rick

Comment: You should make some attempt to format the query in your question.

Comment: apologies gordon - i'm a rare user of stackoverflow and i wasn't across the ctrl+K business of indenting code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for existing answers before asking.

1) [How to return the date part only from a SQL Server datetime datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype)

SQlServer2008 and above:

```
select CONVERT(date, getdate())
```

2) [Write a number with two decimal places SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441600/write-a-number-with-two-decimal-places-sql-server)

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),YOURCOLUMN)
```

Comment: Thanks Shep - with regards to converting to decimal - if the field doesn't have a value in it - it returns as .00 - how do I get it to return 0.00?