# sql cast to str with zero after dot

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can i get '186.60' string from 186.6 number in sql ?

```
select( 186.6::varchar);
```

result is

```
'186.6'
```

Comment: can you provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: you might want to convert decimal places: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441600/write-a-number-with-two-decimal-places-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `to_char()` from [Data formatting functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html).

```
 select to_char(186.6, 'FM999D90');
 to_char 
---------
 186.60
```

Where `9` represents not significant digits and `0` represents significant digits. The `FM`(fill mode) preserves leading and trailing zeros.

Answer (score 0):

```
select(162.4::numeric(10,2)::varchar);
```

will return

```
162.40
```